# Removing apache information from http request

Tags: apache-2.2

I want to remove Apache web server information from http requests. I have already implemented `ServerTokens Prod` and that has reduced the information to just :

`Server: Apache`

now, I want to remove this information from requests as well. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Server` cannot be unset, sorry.  See [here](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=40026).

If you're content with just changing the string, `mod_security` can do it (`SecServerSignature`), as could a proxy of some kind (perversely, even an Apache proxy) in front of your server.

Removing it completely can certainly be done.. but I'm not aware of out-of-the-box software off the top of my head.

Answer (score 6):

```
yum install mod_security
```

edit file `/etc/httpd/conf.d/mod_security.conf`

```
<IfModule mod_security2.c>
    # This is the ModSecurity Core Rules Set.
    SecServerSignature " " ## add this
    # Basic configuration goes in here
    Include modsecurity.d/*.conf
    Include modsecurity.d/base_rules/*.conf
```

**SecServerSignature " "** will hide Server: apache into Server :

ref: http://forums.cpanel.net/f5/disable-serversignature-off-not-working-78468.html